# How to set Symbol levels in renderer by PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, rendering

I know that can use `renderer.setUsingSymbolLevels(True)` to enable the symbol levels, by how can I set the symbol level by PyQGIS? I have tried many methods, but none of them can implement this function. It is very important to have a friend who might help me to answer this question.